# How do I find the formula for the $n$th term of $1/3-2/9+4/27-8/81+\cdots$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to determine the convergence of the following series:
$$\frac{1}{3} - \frac{2}{9} + \frac{4}{27} - \frac{8}{81} + \cdots$$
I am having trouble in finding the formula for the $n$-th term..

Can sombody help me with that?

Comment: ...disregard that. I aw your numerators as 1,2,3,4... for some reason.

Comment: I would also add that you can search for a bit of information about alternating series tests.

Answer (score 1):

We see that the numerator are the powers of 2, and the denominator the powers of 3.

So the series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{2^{n-1}}{3^{n}}$, or $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{3}{(\frac{-2}{3})}^n$. 
We see that this is a geometric series with common ratio $\frac{-2}{3}$ and starting term $a_0=1/3$. So just use the geometric series sum formula, and $S=\frac{1}{5}$

Comment: Your first term isn't the same as OP's.  That won't affect *whether or not* it converges.  But it will affect *what it converges to*.

Comment: Sorry, ill edit my post

Answer (score 0):

You can see that the $n$-th term is given by $$(-1)^n \frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}$$

So you want to estabilish the convergence of the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{2^n}{3^{n+1}}$$

Do you know how to do that? Do you know what the Leibniz test says?

Comment: It says that if 0 is less than a_n+1_ and less than equal to a_n_ and the limit of a_n_ = 0 as n approaches infinity  that it converges.

Comment: @John Exactly. Now I think it's pretty clear that $a_n \to 0$, right? You just need to see if $a_{n+1} \le a_n$ or not. Can you do that?

Comment: I think I can do it. I have a question, so what would the a initial be equal to?

Comment: @John You mean $a_0$? Well it seems that $a_0 = 1/3$. Anyhow if you're only interested in wether a series converges or not, you don't care about the first terms; the only thing that matters is what happens near $\infty$

Comment: Oh okay. I was looking at my notes and saw that the Alternating series test formula was when n=1, does it make a difference if it starts when n=0?

Comment: @John no it does not. You can also say that the first $10^{10}$ terms of that sequence are in the form $n^n$, and from then on they are again in the form we have given before. Does not change a thing, you have to show that there exists a $N > 0$ such that $a_{n+1} < a_n$ for all $n > N$. You don't care what happens "before" ie. to a finite number of terms. Only think about what happens near $\infty$ if you're only interested in wether the series converges or not.